# JPA not generating queries correctly

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, named-query

I'm generating a brand new project with SpringBoot Initializer and the pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JpaDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JpaDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I created a Model and a Repository as follows:

```
package com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER_DETAILS")
@Data
public class OrderModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="MID")
    private String mid;
}
```

```
package com.example.JpaDemo.data.repo;

import com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface OrderModelRepo extends ListCrudRepository<OrderModel,Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "select o from OrderModel o where o.mid = ?1")
    List<OrderModel> findByMid(String mid, Sort sort);
    
}
```

I have used an H2 database and configured the following on application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

And I found an exception as the following:

```
2024-02-06T16:58:20.645-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create         : Created new SQL alias : om1_0
2024-02-06T16:58:20.646-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.create         : Registration of TableGroup [StandardTableGroup(com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel)] with identifierForTableGroup [com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel] for NavigablePath [com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel] 
2024-02-06T16:58:20.651-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.results.graph.AST      : DomainResult Graph:
 \-EntityResultImpl [com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel]
 |  \-BasicFetch [com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel.mid]

2024-02-06T16:58:20.652-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.sql.ast.tree           : SQL AST Tree:
    SelectStatement {
      FromClause {
        StandardTableGroup (om1 : com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel) {
          primaryTableReference : order_details as om1_0
        }
      }
    }

2024-02-06T16:58:20.654-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : Static SQL for entity: com.example.JpaDemo.data.entity.OrderModel
2024-02-06T16:58:20.654-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Version select: select id from order_details where id=?
2024-02-06T16:58:20.654-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Insert (0): insert into order_details (mid,id) values (?,default)
2024-02-06T16:58:20.654-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Update (0): update order_details set mid=? where id=?
2024-02-06T16:58:20.654-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     :  Delete (0): delete from order_details where id=?
2024-02-06T16:58:20.663-06:00  INFO 77103 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-02-06T16:58:20.664-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@3120495d] to SessionFactoryImplementor [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@ba86c53]
2024-02-06T16:58:20.664-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.query.named.NamedObjectRepository    : Checking 0 named HQL queries
2024-02-06T16:58:20.664-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.query.named.NamedObjectRepository    : Checking 0 named SQL queries
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.Table              : No alter strings for table : order_details
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry      : Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@807c1e8
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry      : Registering SessionFactory: 96bb0030-9db8-4666-b65b-bdc4fef5d825 (<unnamed>)
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry      : Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : Instantiated SessionFactory
2024-02-06T16:58:20.685-06:00  INFO 77103 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-02-06T16:58:20.738-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator    : Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
2024-02-06T16:58:20.784-06:00  INFO 77103 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2024-02-06T16:58:20.856-06:00 DEBUG 77103 --- [           main] cResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl : JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)

java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.buildNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1076) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:954) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNamedQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.createNamedQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.hasNamedQuery(NamedQuery.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.getCountQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:204) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.example.JpaDemo.JpaDemoApplication.main(JpaDemoApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
```

I found that internally it is trying to find a Named query called OrderModel.findByMid.count but is not able to find any and is there when the exception is thrown.

If I replace the @Query annotation with the following:
`@Query(value="SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE MID = ?1", countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE MID = ?1", nativeQuery = true) List<OrderModel> findOrderByMid(String mid);`

The exception is no longer thrown. I assume that by the time hibernate or JPA is trying to generate the query, something weird is happening, but I'm not able to find what is the configuration I should use in order to avoid this exceptions on every @Query statement I create.

I don't want to use native queries as I will lose some of the features JPA is providing by using JPQL. I'm stuck at this point. Could someone please help me on this?

I'm expecting not to get the exception and changing the log level is not an option for me.